# Get AZURE AD USER,GROUP,ROLE creation and modified date

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I have used graph API and implemented all features.Now I want to get created date and modified date of User,Group,Role.I have tried looking so many posts and the graph API return type too but not getting any luck. Kindly help if anyone already worked on similar kind of requirement.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As I know, Creation and Modification date information of User, Group, Role could not be directly retrieved by using [Azure AD Graph API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/api-catalog). So far, you could leverage [AD Audit Report Events](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-reporting-audit-events/) to retrieve the audit record. Also, you could follow this [tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-reporting-api-audit-reference/) for getting started with AD Auditing/Reporting APIs which are currently in beta.